# Range operator in C# for arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array int array

```
arr1 = new int[2,2,2];
```

I'd like to create another array, this time 2D, which would be a part of the `arr1`.

Sudo code:

```
arr2 = arr1[..,..,2]
```

`..` means all elements

(create 2D array from `arr1` for trird dimension (rank) index equals 2)

But it looks like there is no a range operator for arrays in C#. Am I right, or I overlooked something?

In other languages thre are some range operators marking all elements, for example: `..` or `:`

I'd like to avoid iterate over `arr1` array.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you're asking for, but no - there's nothing like this within the C# language itself.

Comment: I assume you mean something like the slcing in Python where you extract just a single slice from your 3D-cube. Maybe you should clearify your question a bit.

Comment: The range operators I was referencing to come from MatLAB and TestStand `..` or `:` mean all elements in range or all elements from dimension/rank. I don't know how it is in Python.

Comment: The operators work like select statements

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, you right. That is my intention. But I was comming from different programming environments than you so maybe why it was recognised by the others. `..` and `:` are well known in TestStand and MatLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange that Google brings you to such an old question, but there are now range operators (`..`) for C# 8+

For example:

```
var testArray = new[] { a, b, c, d, e, f };

var a = testArray[..]; // gets all elements (a,b,c,d,e,f)
var b = testArray[0..3]; // gets first 3 elements (a,b,c)
var c = testArray[3..5]; // gets elements 3 and 4 (d,e)
var d = testArray[^3..]; // gets all elements starting from 3
// but count starts from the end, that is testArray.Length - 3 (d,e,f)
```

See more examples here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension

```
public static void getRange(this int[] array, int start, int end) {
    //your for loop
}
```

Then use `arr1.getRange(1,2)`

But there is no builtin operator.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to do looping

Comment: "But there is no builtin operator.", i suggested a shortcut you could use in your project, even though it is not the solution you experienced in different languages